# Keep track of references modifications to update original class

Tags: c++, reference

This is a minimal example

```cpp
class test
{
private:
    std::vector<double> values;
    double max;

public:
    double at(int i) const {return values[i];}
    double& at(int i) {return values[i];}
}
```

I often use my second method to modify some values of the vector in the class.
My question is : "Is there a way to update `max` each time I modify my vector thanks to a reference, without changing the method prototype". I know I could use a setter fonction instead but I want to know if there's the possibility to do without.

Comment: You can count how many times the second overload is called, but I don't think there's any way of knowing if the caller actually *modified* the reference or not.

Comment: It's quite a broad question. The way I've solved it in the past is with an observer pattern. You would wrap your `double` into a type that will emit some kind of event upon modification. Then, your test class subscribes to this event for each element added.